# Popover/Tooltip with buttons like in iOS autocorrect

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

[image: Example]

How can I create a tooltip like this in my iPad app? Is this an `UIPopoverController`? Or some kind of custom tooltip view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use UIMenuController. There's menuItems property to set custom items. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html